# SED - replace line number with new text and variables in text file

Tags: bash, sed

I have problem using `sed` in Bash, could somebody help me? This `sed` command works fine...

**`sed` command**

```
sed -i '3s/.*/...test_text.../g' FILE.txt
```

**`sed` commnad + variables**

but I when I use variable in the SED for the new text, new line, then I get an error ... sed -e #expression #1, unknow option to `s'

```
line_number="3"
new_text="...test_text..."
FILE="FILE.txt"
sed -i "${line_number}s/.*/${new_text}/" $FILE
```

Could you please help and explain me, what is wrong and how can/should I write this? I had tried many other versions, also I have red other topic...but I am stucked. Thanks for any help in advance...

Answer (score 3):

If your `new_text` variable contains slashes, injecting them into your `sed` command would generate a syntax error by the internal `sed` expression parser.

The solution to that is to use another character as the delimiter for the `s` command, for example, a comma:

```bsh
sed -i "$line_number s,.*,$new_text," "$file"
```

If you have values in `new_text` that are so varied that you can't reliably pick a delimiter character that is guaranteed to not occur in your string, then consider using the `c` command instead.  One may use the `c` (change) command to replace a line.

```bsh
sed -i "$line_number c \\$new_text" "$file"
```

The `c` command takes the new text after a `\` and a newline.  Both the `\` and the newline seem to be optional with GNU `sed`. I'm using a `\` above to allow `$new_text` to start with a backslash, and I'm escaping it with another backslash since we're in a double-quoted string.

A portable `sed` command would need to look like

```bsh
sed "$line_number c \\
$new_text" "$file"
```

The above assumes that each newline in `$new_text` is preceded by a `\` character, and that any literal backslash that is part of the data is escaped as `\\`.

---

You could also use `awk`.  Below, I'm using GNU `awk` to enable in-place editing:

```bsh
text=$new_text awk -i inplace -v lineno="$line_number" \
    'NR == lineno { print ENVIRON["text"]; next }; 1' "$file"
```

This assumes, apart from GNU `awk`, that your new text is in `$new_text`, that the line number is in `$line_number`, and that the pathname of the file is in `$file`.

The new text is passed via the environment variable `text` into the `awk` code, while the line number is given to the internal `awk` variable `lineno` on the command line.  When finding the given line number, the code outputs the value of the `text` environment variable instead of printing the current line.

Using GNU `awk` in this way puts no special restriction on the value of `$new_text`.

Example (GNU `awk` on my system is called `gawk`):

```bsh
$ cat file.txt
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

```bsh
$ new_text='hello world'
$ line_number=2
$ file=./file.txt
```

```bsh
$ text=$new_text gawk -i inplace -v lineno="$line_number" \
    'NR == lineno { print ENVIRON["text"]; next }; 1' "$file"
```

```bsh
$ cat file.txt
Line 1
hello world
Line 3
```

Comment: @don_crissti I would honestly go with `awk` in place of escaping the inserted string, for the sake of minimizing the amount of code and keeping it maintainable.

Comment: I have tried the code with AWK. I get no error, but also no change in File. Could you please retype the code, command....with AWK? Where could I read meaning of the command line typed above in AWK to understand this specific command line (not AWK in general)? What does the ENVIRON stands for?

Comment: @Scripter `ENVIRON` is a special `awk` array that contains all environment variables. I'm using it to pull out the value of the `text` environment variable.  The value of that environment variable is set on the command line from the `$new_text` value.  It is assumed that `$new_text` is the new text that should be inserted and that it should be inserted in place of line `$line_number` in the file referred to by `$file`.

Comment: I am trying the AWK code typed above and it makes me no change in file. Could you please post code example, picture, etc.? I cannot figure out, what do I do wrong.

Comment: @Scripter See added example.

Comment: doesnt work for me..........

Comment: @Scripter What does `awk --version` output on your system? I'm assuming it's either not GNU `awk`, or you are using a very old version of the tool. If so, I will update my answer to fit that.

Comment: GNU awk 4.2.1. I am trying tu use AWK NR=...., but I have same problem to use variable for new text

Comment: @Scripter You have a recent enough `awk`. The _only_ difference between my variables and yours is that I call my filename variable `file` with lower-case letters. That's all. You should not change anything at all about the `awk `command. With the `new_text` and `line_number` and `file` variables set, it should be a matter of copying and pasting. Don't try to change anything about the `awk ` code itself.  Just try to recreate my example at the end of the answer, and change the vales of the variables.

Comment: the "main" command (text=..., gawk....) is written in line? what does the slash mean? where could I read explanation about meaning of executing this code?

Comment: @Scripter The backslash at the end of the first line escapes the newline. It's a common way to wrap a long command into multiple lines for readability. It's a line continuation. You could type it _exactly the way that I have presented it here_, or you could remove the backslash at the end of the first line and type it all on one long line.

Comment: @Scripter I honestly don't know how much more I need to explain about this single command. Just make sure that the three variables that I mentioned earlier are set correctly and then just copy and paste the command from the website into your terminal. I gove an easy to recreate example that you could play around with.  There is no tricks or hidden secrets here, but I can't give you a whole lecture on basic stuff lke variables and how the command line works.

Comment: thanks for feedback about backslash, could you share, provide...stuff, whatever about variables, command line...?

Answer (score 0):

If you enter the variables and the command exectly like above, you'll see there is no error. The problem is with the real content of `new_text`. I guess it contains a slash like `new_text=usr/bin`. Then after the variables have been substituted, you'll get

```
sed -i "3s/.*/usr/bin/" FILE.txt
```

So the line gets replaced by `usr`, and `sed` continues to interpret the flags of the `s` command and finds the `b` of `bin`, which is not a legal option.

If you know the range of legal characters of `new_text`, then simply choose a character outside that range as delimiter, like

```
sed -i "${line_number}s~.*~${new_text}~" $FILE
```

Comment: the variable new_text contain special characters - slash, single, double quotes, higher than....

I have tried the version with paragraph ...§... but it doesnt work, error - delimiter char is not single-byte character

what do I type wrong?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Forgot that `§` won't work. I replaced it by `~` in my example. But of course, if you have some other special characters like a backslash, you may run into other problems.